# Is positioning lots of content blocks with position:relative sloppy coding?

Tags: css, positioning

I find myself placing a lot of divs, images and content in general with position:relative to stick to the design I'm following.

For example if I wanted to place a form closer to the top I'd put in :

```
.form_class{
    position:relative;
    bottom:150px;
}
```

Since the element keeps its position in the flux, I'd then have to put every other element upwards of 150px with position:relative as to keep the gap closed.

I feel like this is sloppy programming, how do real web integrators position their elements ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a potential problem with using relative positioning.

If you are using the relative positioning to circumvent a problem with a gap, the problem is still there in the background. If the gap comes from a margin for example, then the margin is still there. If you don't know where the margin comes from, you don't know if it's the same in all browsers, and you don't know if any seemingly unrelated changes in the markup might change the margin.

Also, as you mention, you are just moving the gap from the top of the element to the bottom of the element, so you have to keep adjusting all the elements that follow. With each adjustment you are potentially adding another level of insecurity, where the layout might break in another browser.

Most browsers have a developer tool, where you can inspect an element to see exactly what CSS is applied to the element, and what the margins and padding are. You can use that to find out where gaps come from, so that you can remove them at the source instead of circumventing them.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to position elements, from margins and paddings, absolute positioning, floats, parent containers, explicit widths and heights.  Without seeing your markup it's hard to critic but usually there are better ways than relative positioning.  If you want to post some markup try http://jsfiddle.net